# How to functionalize countdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a countdown timer and coded this in with HTML and CSS, but I wasn't able to make it functional using jQuery.  How can I functionalize this countdown? Here is the HTML structure I prefer the countdown to be in:

```
    <div id="counter-container">
      <div class="counter-box">
        <div class="counter"><p class="counter-p">#</p></div>
        <p class="counter-box-p">days</p>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-box">
        <div class="counter"><p class="counter-p">#</p></div>
        <p class="counter-box-p">hours</p>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-box">
        <div class="counter"><p class="counter-p">#</p></div>
        <p class="counter-box-p">minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-box">
        <div class="counter"><p class="counter-p">#</p></div>
        <p class="counter-box-p">seconds</p>
      </div>
```

As you can see, I have already added paragraph elements for days, hours etc, therefore I do not want to embed any extra text through jQuery.

P.S. Could anyone please tell me how to set a new countdown date?

Comment: Have you attempted to implement the countdown yourself? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Did get the countdown running, however its format was very different than time and had struggle to customize it.

Comment: Let me rephrase my answer: The jQuery plugin, that I am trying to get to work, is made so that you just assign the div (or any other element) and the jQuery will just make all the other necessary elements inside that DIV (e.g. Hours, minutes etc.). However, when I go to google chrome developer tools to retrieve the class and ids of these elements, I am not able to, (starts glitching) so that I can assign some css to make it look like my design and not the default one.   Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function counter(count) {
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    var temp;
    $("p#d").html(Math.floor(count/(60*60*24)));
    temp = count%(60*60*24);
    $("p#h").html(Math.floor(temp/(60*60)));
    temp = count%(60*60);
    $("p#m").html(Math.floor(temp/(60)));
    temp = count%(60);
    $("p#s").html(temp);
    if (count == 0) {
         alert("time's up");
         clearInterval(countdown);       
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
}

counter(60*60*24*2);
```

​[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfLAB/)

**EDIT-1:**

counter gets time as seconds.

```
counter(10); //10 seconds
counter(10*60) //600 seconds -> 10 minutes.
counter(10*60*60) //36000 seconds -> 600 minutes -> 10 hour
```

**EDIT-2:**

if you want it to work `Date` based, you should change function like this,

```
function counter(futureDate) {
  var today = new Date(); // today
  count = Math.floor((futureDate-today)/1000);
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    var temp;
    $("p#d").html(Math.floor(count/(60*60*24)));
    temp = count%(60*60*24);
    $("p#h").html(Math.floor(temp/(60*60)));
    temp = count%(60*60);
    $("p#m").html(Math.floor(temp/(60)));
    temp = count%(60);
    $("p#s").html(temp);
    if (count == 0) {
         alert("time's up");
         clearInterval(countdown);       
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
}

counter(new Date(2012,4,8)); // May 8, 2012 00:00:00
/* counter(new Date(2012,4,8,15,49,10)); // May 8, 2012 15:49:00 */
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NfLAB/1/

Comment: Great! Any instruction on how I can adjust the time? Since I don't get anything of those number :) sorry.

Comment: You can just change the initializer - it is currently set to count down for 2 full days. 60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours * 2 days). For 2 hours just change the line to "counter(120);", or "counter(60*2)".

Comment: Hey, the code works like a charm! Thanks. But, is there any way of giving the date and the code does the rest of the job of working out the time from now onto the date? This is because right now, I am working on a project which is still local and on my computer. So therefore everytime I reload the page or change something the timer just resets itself... I get why this happens. Anyway, if there is nothing to do that, I have no problem with changing the time on upload. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShadAsinger look my updated answer again, I've appended Date based function.

Comment: Wow great, ur the best! Wish I knew jQuery like u do :)

Comment: @ShadAsinger :) thanks, but I'm not the best, but glad to help you.