# how to create counter by jquery count down by num of days

Tags: javascript, jquery

ello I want to create counter  which i specify date for example `(2012/07/01) date X`

counting down while `date now <  date X`

using **jQuery**  or any other **java Script** library

please show me how i can do this

or give me some hint in my case

***and this counter still counter down by ( -1 second ) until Arvie to this date for example when we open web site during 2 month and show in index this counter until to open it***

Comment: FYI - jQuery is not a language it is a library written to ease somethings done with the help of JavaScript. What have you tried to implement this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to functionalize countdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049368/how-to-functionalize-countdown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like this.

Remember to create an element with an id called 'Example', and set the date you want though..

```
 function updateTimer(){
    // Get the element to append to
    var counter = document.getElementById("Example");
    // Set the targetDate
    var targetDate = new Date("July 27, 2012 19:30:00");

    var remainingSeconds = ~ ~((targetDate - new Date()) / 1000);
    var remainingTime = {
        "days": remainingSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24),
        "hours": (remainingSeconds % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60),
        "minutes": (remainingSeconds % (60 * 60)) / 60,
        "seconds": remainingSeconds % 60
    };

    var str = "Time left is :: ";
    for (var i in remainingTime) {
        str += ~ ~remainingTime[i] + " " + i + ", ";
    }
    // Store the result in the element
    counter.innerHTML = str.substring(0, str.length - 2);
 }

 // Update the timer every 1 second
 setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

Here's the JSFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/fqPqS/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a javascript library for that.
You can just do it like this:

```
var date=new Date();
var day=date.getDate();
var month=date.getMonth();
var year=date.getFullYear();
var now=year+'/'+month+'/'+day;
var x='2012/7/1';
if(now==x){
    doSomthing();
};
```

Comment: Sorry i want to display counter by secend and mints and days

Comment: and this counter still counter down by **( -1  second  )** until Arvie to this date for example when we open web site during 2 month and show in index this counter until to open it